# command ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com not working

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to connect to remote repo through gitbash.

1. I have added origin https://gitlab.com/xx123456/myproject.git
2. I have created ssh key pair
3. I added public key to gitlab.com

Gitlab docs https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html provide this command in setup

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com
```

When I run this command in gitbash

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com:xx123456/myproject.git
```

I get error:

```
Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com/xx123456/myproject.git: Name or service not known
```

I suspect maybe I am replacing example.com incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you be specific?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You are executing `ssh -T git@gitlab.com:xx123456/myproject.git`, this is what you are doing wrong. I do not understand the question. You can't ssh login to a directory. Probably you meant to `git clone`. You did not state what you _want_ to do.

Comment: thanks. I am new with bash commands. so i pretty much blindly was doing stuff.

Comment: @KamilCuk, what I want: "I want to connect to remote repo through gitbash". First sentence:)

Comment: Then execute `ssh git@gitlab.example.com` to connect to `gitalb.example.com` server as user `git` getting a secured shell. Then, in that shell, you can `cd` to the directory you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the example domain with the domain you're connecting to.

Since in your case, you're connecting to `gitlab.com`, it would look like this:

`ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

However, the `ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com` command is primarily to check that the SSH keys have been added correctly to your account. So, it's not a *required* part of the configuration, just used for verification.

If everything has been configured correctly, you should get a "Welcome `@yourusername`" message from the GitLab server.